# Evaluate JavaScript code using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm trying to use PhantomJS to run some JavaScript from an ad server and parse out the response object for information about the ad that was served. This is readily available from Firefox/Chrome Dev Tools, but I need to access that same information from a server. I can get Phantom to run, but as soon as I try to include external JS `page.includeJs("http://www.someadserver.com/config.js?nwid=1909"`and access variables that are set via that external JS `someadserver.setup({ domain: 'http://www.someadserver.com'});` it fails miserably. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
"use strict";

var page = require('webpage').create();

page.content = `    
  <html>    
    <head>    
        <script>    
            someadserver.setup({ domain: 'http://www.someadserver.com'});    
        </script>    
       <title>The title of the web page.</title>    
    </head>    
    <body>    
    <div class="ads_leaderboard">    
        <!-- position: leaderboard -->    
        <script>    
            someadserver.call( "std" , {    
                siteId: 100806,    
                pageId: 656377,    
                target: ""
            });    
        </script>    
    </div>    
    <div id="foo">this is foo</div>    
    </body>    
  </html>`;

var title = page.evaluate(function (s) {
    page.includeJs(
      "http://www.someadserver.com/config.js?nwid=1909",
      function() {
        return document.querySelector(s).innerText;
    }, 'title');
});

console.log(title);

phantom.exit(1);
```

**EDIT 1:**

I've simplified my script (below) and I'm clearly missing something. When I run the script below using `bin/phantomjs /srv/phantom_test.js` the only output I get is `end page`. Why aren't the rest of the console.log statements executing?

```
"use strict";

var page = require('webpage').create();

page.content = "<html>" +
"<head>" +
"   <title>The title of the web page.</title>" +
"</head>" +
"<body>" +
"<div id=\"foo\">this is foo</div>" +
"</body>" +
"</html>";

page.includeJs("http://www.someadserver.com/config.js?nwid=1909", function() {
    console.log('start function');
    var title = page.evaluate(function(s){
        return document.querySelector(s).innerText;
    }, 'title');
    console.log(title);
    console.log('end function');
});

console.log('end page');

phantom.exit();
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the docs?  http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/include-js.html.  Can you elaborate more on the actual error you are getting?  I wonder if 's' is undefined...what object do you expect that to be?

Comment: `phantom.exit(1);` Interesting - do eliberately exit with an error code?

Comment: Copy/Pasted `phantom.exit(1);` from somewhere, too new in PhantomJS to have done that on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The stuff inside `page.evaluate` is executed in the context of a target page **as if that code was *inside* of that page**.

`page.includeJS(...)` will not be a valid code on a `someadserver.com`.

The correct way is vice versa:

```
page.includeJs("http://www.someadserver.com/config.js?nwid=1909", function() {
    var title = page.evaluate(function(s){
        return document.querySelector(s).innerText;
    }, 'title');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first snippet doesn't work, because assigning a value to `page.content` immediately executes it. So, `someadserver.setup(...)` is executed immediately as if the page is actually loaded, but at this time the `page.includeJs(...)` call hasn't happened yet.
You should be able to actually include script that you want to run inside of the page source:

```
var content = `    
  <html>    
    <head>
        <script src="http://www.someadserver.com/config.js?nwid=1909"></script>
        <script>    
            someadserver.setup({ domain: 'http://www.someadserver.com'});    
        </script>    
       <title>The title of the web page.</title>    
    </head>    
    <body>    
    <div class="ads_leaderboard">    
        <!-- position: leaderboard -->    
        <script>    
            someadserver.call( "std" , {    
                siteId: 100806,    
                pageId: 656377,    
                target: ""
            });    
        </script>    
    </div>    
    <div id="foo">this is foo</div>    
    </body>    
  </html>`;

page.setContent(content, "http://www.someadserver.com/");
var title = page.evaluate(function (s) {
    return document.querySelector(s).innerText;
}, 'title');

console.log(title);

phantom.exit();
```

I've also used `page.setContent` in order to set the domain, so that further script loading is not broken. When a page source is assigned to `page.content`, the default URL is actually about:blank and you don't want that.

Further problems with your first snippet:

- The beginnings and ends of `page.evaluate` and `page.includeJs` don't match up!
- There is no `page` inside of `page.evaluate`, because the page context is sandboxed!

---

Your second snippet doesn't work, because `page.includeJs(...)` is a asynchronous function (it has a callback!), so you're exiting the script too early.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Very helpful. Your snippet doesn't error, which is great, but I'm running into something that I first started experiencing when I played around with this. Running `bin/phantomjs /srv/phantom_test.js` just hangs, indefinitely. Is there any way to monitor the incoming/outcoming connections to see what's going on? I've tried the examples here (http://phantomjs.org/network-monitoring.html) to no avail.

Comment: Using the --debug option, I can see that the script is hanging here... 
2016-08-16T15:49:59 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/fs.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r")))
2016-08-16T15:49:59 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/system.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r")))
2016-08-16T15:49:59 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/webpage.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r")))

Comment: I'm not sure what that might mean. Which PhantomJS version are you using? I'm not sure an old version supports multi-line strings.

Comment: phantomjs-2.1.1 on my mac osx does not support ` for multi-line strings.